# Dynamic content inside scrollview lost last view

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have ScrollView with LinearLayout and button inside:

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/card_color"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_leave"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/leave" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then in code I add view to `layout_list`:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        .inflate(R.layout.item_member, mLayoutMemberList, true);
```

If I add not many items, then `button_leave` is visible. But if I add a lot of items (more then showing on the screen) then button is not visible on the screen even if I scroll down.

**Update:**

Looks like it is bug of `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`. I change it to simple linear layout and all work good.

Comment: can you please try changing height of parent LinearLayout to match parent, currently it is wrap current.    'android:layout_height="wrap_content"'

Comment: Unfortunately it not help and it provider lint warning: should use wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

I think layout view is working fine and try below code,

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
 View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list, null, true);
```